# How to paint the differences in red?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I create a website using Forge-Viewer, it implements loading several models in one window, as shown in this article https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer. I need to select two, almost identical files, which differ from each other only by the properties of one element, and paint over these differences in red. How can I paint the differences between two identical uploaded files red?

This is for a new site. I have already tried all the methods and recommendations available on the Internet,but none of them helped me solve my problem.

My code is fully consistent with the code from this source 
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer

I expect that I can finally paint the differences in red, but so far I have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to compare the properties by querying the `viewer.model.getBulkProperties` (dev doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Model.html#getBulkProperties)) or `viewer.search` (dev doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#search)) interface (whichever works better depending on your specific use cases) and to make external IDs:

```
let model = viewer.impl.modelQueue().findModel(modelId) || viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()[modelSequence] //Set the model to query against

model.getBulkProperties(dbid,['propname1','propnam2'],rst=>{...},err=>{...}) //Retrieve the properties with filtering conditions and compare them

model.search('keywords',dbids=>{...}, err=>{...}) //Query dbids with properties matching keywords
```

Then take the `dbids` with discrepancies and highlight them with a theming color (dev doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#setThemingColor)):

```
viewer.setThemingColor(dbid, THREE.Vector4, model)
```

Comment: Here is a snippet of my code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGmXOv .
And this is a mistake that I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findModel' of undefined".
I know that I do something netak, but I do not understand what. 
Thank you.

Comment: Access `modelQueue` after the model is loaded e.g in your hook to the `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` before then it is yet to be initialized and hence undefined

Comment: This is my code [link of my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLzMNL)

And what is the reason that I get this answer in console? I kinda did everything right ...
findModel: ƒ (b)
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on  (<anonymous>:2:14)]
length: 1
name: ""

Comment: I use this code I got a model Id, but I don’t understand how I can differentiate between two almost identical files that differ from each other only by their property. I would like to paint in a different color or isolate those elements that are different from each other, and if they do not differ, then leave it unchanged. What method or what should I pay attention to?

[link on of my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaRqbq)